# («)Помните(?) («)По одежке встречают, по уму провожают»(?)

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

1. Помните? «По одежке встречают, по уму провожают».
2. Помните: «По одежке встречают, по уму провожают»?
3. Помните: по одежке встречают, по уму провожают? (Учитывая, что пословицы без родового слова в тексте, кажется, не кавычатся.)

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить такие варианты (выбор зависит от текста, разные формы имеют разные смысловые оттенки):

Утвердительный вариант: Как вы помните, по одежке встречают, по уму провожают. Помните: по одежке встречают, по уму провожают.

Вопросительный вариант: Помните, по одежке встречают, по уму провожают?

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Вообще говоря, "помните", "как вы помните", "если вы помните" часто выступают в роли вводных слов, при этом вопросительный знак не ставится, если это утвердительные предложения. Также встречаются вопросительные варианты, если автор не уверен в своем предположении и хочет задать вопрос, в том числе риторического характера.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Христос, как вы помните, Пилату на это не ответил.
Помните, как у Цветаевой: "Мы спаяны блаженно и тепло, как правое и левое крыло".
Помните, как о них было сказано в газетке: "Город наш украсился, благодаря попечению гражданского правителя, садом, состоящим из тенистых дерев…" 
Помните у Брюсова: "Сокровища, заложенные в чувстве, я берегу для творческих минут"?
Помните, мы играли в снежки и возводили снежную крепость, когда в позапрошлом году был снегопад?

Comment: Здесь нужно именно передать вопросительную интонацию. А вариант с вопросительным знаком и двоеточием без кавычек не подходит?

Comment: Мне кажется, что  для этого варианта интонацию трудно подобрать (двоеточие обозначает увеличенную паузу с понижением голоса). Я сначала тоже написала этот вариант, но потом его убрала. Может быть, так: По одежке встречают, по уму провожают, помните?

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Помните? По одежке встречают, по уму провожают.

Comment: Пословицы не надо выделять кавычками.

Comment: Варианты: Помните?.. По одежке встречают, по уму провожают.  Помните, – по одежке встречают, по уму провожают?

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие уместно там, где наиболее может проявиться ее разъяснительно-пояснительная функция.
Так что оформление вполне возможно. Помните: По одежке встречают, по уму провожают?

Надо, однако отметить,что двоеточие более книжный знак. Если вам необходимо передать разговорную речь на письме, лучше использовать запятую, т. е. оформить как вводное слово. Подробнее о двоеточии см.: [справочник Валгина Н.С.. Активные процессы в современном русском языке: Учебное пособие для студентов вузов. - М.: Логос, 2003. - 304 с., 2003](http://sci-book.com/yazyik-russkiy/aktivnyie-protsessyi-sovremennom-russkom.html).

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно без кавычек. Если это вопросительное предложение, то не двоеточие, а тире.

Или уж так: *Помните? По одежке встречают – по уму провожают.*